# GUI designer in netbeans does not load a specific JPanel designer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-8

It has been a few days that I've started using netbeans's gui designer.
I have built and tested all the panels I need for my project, 
but today when I wanted to add some action listeners to my MainPanel.java class and tried to open it in design view, it didn't open. 
It shows loading the panel but there is no sign of viewing it. 
I can see the JPanel's code and I can see and open my other panels' design view. 
It's only this one. 
I searched the net but I couldn't find a proper answer. 
Can anyone help me? 
Does anyone have any idea what is the problem?

I'm using windows 7 and netbeans 8.0.2.
here are my design classes:

```
FinancialDocumentsJFrame.java
MainPanel.java 
BillEntryPanel.java 
ReceiptEntryPanel.java 
SearchPanel.java 
PaymentJFrame.java
```

I can open the design view of other classes. It's only MainPanel.java  that dose not open and can see its code only. I'm also using some other java classes, too. Rather than form classes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new class and copied the existing class code in to it and it worked again.

Good Luck with your codes.